# Riemann Hypothesis and Prime summation

Tags: number-theory

In the [OEIS page for the decimal expansion of $\pi$](https://oeis.org/A000796) there's the following curious comment:

> $$\pi = 3\prod_{\substack{t = \Im(r)\\r = (1/2+it) \\\zeta(r) = 0}}\frac{9+4t^2}{1+4t^2}\iff\text{RH is true}$$

Here, $\Im(r)$ denotes the imaginary part.  So, the product is over all the imaginary parts of the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann Zeta function.

Does anyone have further information about this statement?

**Motivation:**

I found a series with prime arguments that converge to $\pi/3$ and want to discover a connection between the primes and the roots of the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Taking the logarithm, It could be something like the Riemann explicit formula for $\int_1^x \psi_{1/2}(y)\frac{dy}{y}$ where $\psi_{1/2}(x) = \sum_{n < x}\Lambda(n) n^{-1/2}$, evaluated at some $x$

Comment: The comment is due to Dimitris Valianatos. Ask him.

Comment: This question now has a very nice answer at MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/a/285359/41139